# A simple floor equation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**The Problem:**

Solve
$ \lfloor x^2\rfloor $ = 3

**What i tried to do:**

By definition: $ 3 \le x^2 \lt 4 $

Therfore $ \sqrt{3} \le x \lt 2 $

Or $ \sqrt{3} \le -x \lt 2 $ And then $-2 \le x \lt -\sqrt{3} $

So the final solution is **$-2 \le x \lt -\sqrt{3} $**  Or  **$ \sqrt{3} \le x \lt 2 $**

**My Question:**

Is this valid? And if not, How should i write the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. $(-2,\sqrt(3)]\cup [\sqrt(3),2)$ is okay as well

Comment: No, you included x = -2.

Comment: @Dvor, for negative part: this is right $\sqrt{3} \le -x \lt 2,$ but what follows is not. Has to be $-2 \lt x \le -\sqrt{3}.$